# Is it possible to update configuration settings programmatically?

Tags: azure, web-config, azure-web-roles

We are experimenting with deploying an MVC app as an Azure web role. Currently the app is being hosted locally on our server. It has a few appSettings in Web.Config that can be changed by the users as part of the "Administration" module of the application.

I know this isn't a good practice for Azure because there will potentially be multiple instances of the application running with multiple Web.Configs, which makes updating them all a nightmare (if not impossible). My understanding is that the ConfigurationSettings specified in the service definition should be used instead of Web.Config so that settings are defined globally in one place that all the instances of the application can access.

My question is is it possible to programmatically update ConfigurationSettings similar to the way we update Web.Config settings, or would it be better for us to move those settings into a database or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but unfortunately it is definitely not simple to do.

Follow this URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460809.aspx

It talks about a Svc Management API call that you can make to read/write the Service Configuration.  It is a 64-base string which you'll need to decode, find XML flags in it that you want to change and re-encode it back and send it back to the API.

Not pleasant, but doable.

Comment: Yeah...definitely not pleasant. I'm thinking it will be more productive to move the settings into a database :). Thanks for your help!